Is a finite resource that will never run out considered infinite?
I am a regular on many SE sites, although this is my first (but hopefully not last) question on Math SE. My area of expertise is in digital technology- and although I do know more mathematical concepts than most people, I am definitely by no means advanced in maths.
So I ask you kindy, please remember that I have very little mathematical knowledge compared to all of you- so forgive me and understand if this is an obvious or ‘silly’ question. Here we go:
A while ago, some colleagues and friends of mine were discussing an idea we got from someone- I forget who- they might have been reputable, they might not have been.
This is it:
An apple tree has 10 apples at all times- whenever one is picked a new another instantly grows back. This is the same with two and three apples- and so on.
So this is an infinite supply of apples. But there is a finite amount of apples on the tree at one time.
So my question is: does my resource (apple tree)= (∞ apples)? In other words, does my apple tree have infinite apples?
** Is a finite resource that will never run out considered infinite?**
This sounds simple, but by my logic, the tree has ten apples, and can never have more than ten apples. But I can pick an infinite number of apples.
So what one is it? Or is this expressed as something else? I’m really not sure.

THis question is about language, not Mathematics.

For the purpose of a mathematical model (whatever this means, provided some meaning could be given to this) you would just say that there are $10$ apples on the tree at any given time.

@JoséCarlosSantos why is this? I am probably just missing something, sorry.

@SassatelliGiulio that makes sense- I was only wondering if there was other ways to express this mathematically.

@security_paranoid There is no point in dabbling in syntactic substitutions that lose information.

The question is imprecise and forcing yourself to get more specific about what you mean by various words will eventually resolve all confusions. The following are simultaneously true:

At any given point in time there are at most $10$ apples on the tree.

For every positive integer $n$ it is possible to (eventually) acquire $n$ apples from the tree.


The second property could be phrased as saying that the apple tree is an unlimited source of apples, in that there is no bound $N$ on the number of apples one can acquire from it. It's important to distinguish "unlimited" from "infinite"; given that picking an apple requires a specific amount of time, say one second, you can only ever pick finitely many apples in a finite length of time. There is just, by hypothesis, no limit on how large this "finitely many" can get.
There are various related phenomena in mathematics where one has to distinguish carefully between "finite but unbounded" and "infinite"; they are not at all the same thing and people routinely confuse the two by being insufficiently precise. For example this routinely comes up in a classic "disproof" of Cantor's diagonal argument because people get confused about the difference between "the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$" (which is uncountable, and contains infinite subsets) and "the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$" (which is countable, and contains finite subsets that get arbitrarily large).

Thanks very much- great answer. Would things change if an apple could be picked in an infinitely small amount of time?

@security_paranoid: then we're really just getting into semantics, but in that case you could pick infinitely many apples but it still wouldn't sound right to me to say that it's the tree that has infinitely many apples, since again, by hypothesis the tree only ever has at most $10$ apples at a time. At the end of the picking process it's you that has the infinitely many apples.

That makes more sense- it’s the picker that has infinite apples. thanks again for explaining.
